# Swapping pairs of characters in a string

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, swap

Okay, I'm really new to Python and have no idea how to do this:

I need to take a string, say 'ABAB__AB', convert it to a list, and then take the leading index of the pair I want to move and swap that pair with the __. I think the output should look something like this:

`move_chars('ABAB__AB', 0)
'__ABABAB'`

and another example:

`move_chars('__ABABAB', 3)
'BAA__BAB'`

Honestly have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Do you have any preliminary attempts with unwanted results?

Comment: I've had a couple of attempts. But I really have no idea where to even start. I've tried: 

def move_chars(state, pos):
      s = list(state)
      
Really I just have no idea what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

Python strings are immutable, so you can't really modify a string. Instead, you make a new string.

If you want to be able to modify individual characters in a string, you can convert it to a list of characters, work on it, then join the list back into a string.

```
chars = list(str)
# work on the list of characters
# for example swap first two
chars[0], chars[1] = chars[1], chars[0]
return ''.join(chars)
```

Comment: So use commands like .pop() and .append() to move characters around right? But how do I make pairs move around? i.e. take the characters in position 0 and 1, and then swap them with the ones in say 3 and 4?

Comment: @TownofRavens You may want to reconsider your data structure. If you're going to be moving around pairs of letters, especially multiple times, then perhaps you should just stick with a list.

Comment: @TownofRavens If all you want to do is a few swaps, you should use indices, `chars[0], chars[3] = chars[3], chars[0]; chars[1], chars[4] = chars[4], chars[1]`.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I'll incorporate what you both said.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should go to the comment section, but I can't comment because of lack of reputation, so...

You'll probably want to stick with list index swapping, rather than using `.pop()` and `.append()`. `.pop()` *can* remove elements from arbitrary index, but only one at once, and `.append()` can *only* add to the end of the list. So they're quite limited, and it would complicate your code to use them in this kind of problems.

So, well, better stick with swapping with index.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use list slicing to move parts of the string.

```
def move_chars(s, index):
    to_index = s.find('__')                # index of destination underscores
    chars = list(s)                        # make mutable list
    to_move = chars[index:index+2]         # grab chars to move
    chars[index:index+2] = '__'            # replace with underscores
    chars[to_index:to_index+2] = to_move   # replace underscores with chars
    return ''.join(chars)                  # stitch it all back together

print(move_chars('ABAB__AB', 0))
print(move_chars('__ABABAB', 3))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand it now.